# Simple equation on Javascript not working and I can't see the problem

Tags: javascript, equation

I'm trying to solve a simple equation "2^x=y" in javascript, but I can't see what's wrong with it, the browser just seems to enter an infinite loop... Here's the code:

Edit: I changed the code to the whole script so you guys can see, the function that does the equation is the last one. Also apparently I have to talk more in order to edit the post sorry :)

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function SolveEquation(input){
    while(x < input){
        x = Math.pow(2, y);
        y = y+1;
    }
    if(x >= input){
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use global variables. its bad coding, and as you are finding out, makes code impossible to read and debug. pass x & y into your function.

Comment: @VictorGarcia yeah I was supposing that, but maybe that is the part that is wrong ;)

Comment: I just realized I didn't change back x and y to their original variable names temp1 and temp2 respectively

Answer (score 1):

several things seem to be wrong with this code.

1. Never use global variables. pass x & y into your function
2. this is supposed to be a function but its possible for undefined to be returned, which is bad coding for a function. (your only return statement is contained in an if statement)
3. depending on the values of x and "input" its very possible you will never exit the while statement. again bad coding. maybe check that the values are valid, or re-write the function so it always works no matter what values are passed in.

Comment: *but its possible for null to be returned* **Wrong.** The standard return value in Javascript functions is `undefined`, not `null`.

Comment: well depending on your definition of null, its the same thing, but I changed it.

Comment: What do you mean "your definition"? There is a clear definition of null in Javascript, no matter my own.

Comment: I was simply using the English definition of it which means its not returning a value.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like your problem isn't so much Javascript as it your algebra.

Assuming `input` is `y` and you're solving for x, it's:

- `2^x = y`
- `log2(2^x) = log2(y)`
- `x * log2(2) = log2(y)`
- `x * 1 = log2(y)`
- `x = log2(y)`

```js
function SolveEquation(input) {
  return Math.log2(input);
}
```